# What are the int and multiplication signs doing here?

Tags: java, int, rectangles

Can anyone explain what the purpose of the ints are in Rectangle center and Rectangle obstacle? I already understand that an int is a positive or negative whole number. Also why don't I need any ints in Rectangle left and Rectangle right if they are needed in center and obstacle? I'm still new to this so if anyone thinks I should include more code just let me know.

```
Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0,0,WIDTH/9,HEIGHT);
Rectangle right = new Rectangle((WIDTH/9)*8,0,WIDTH/9,HEIGHT);

Rectangle center = new Rectangle((int)((WIDTH/9)* 2.5),(int)((HEIGHT/9)*2.5),(int)  
((WIDTH/9)*5),(HEIGHT/9)*4);
Rectangle obstacle = new Rectangle(WIDTH/2,(int)((HEIGHT/9)*7),
WIDTH/10,HEIGHT/9);
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: any book on java worth its salt will talk about casting. read the rest of the book.

Comment: What does a multiplication sign do anywhere?

Comment: Mkoryak I am reading "Programming video games for the Evil Genius" This code has been in the last three projects with absolutely no explanation on how it works. I wish there was though.

Comment: @MartinMarino I detest those "program video games in language <x>!" books. They rarely teach any actual concept, mostly hodgepodge execution. I would recommend using [Oracle's excellent tutorial set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks. Il look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a strongly typed language, which means every variable has a [data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). However, via [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) you can use the information from one data type and handle it as a different one. Examples of this in Java are [interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) & [subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). You can do this conversion either by implicit or explicit casting. That is what is shown here.

When you use a primitive data type or object name in parentheses before another variable, it [casts](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/TypeCasting.shtml) to another compatible type.

As long as the internal data is compatible, you can convert the type to something else. For example, if the Object in question here was a String:

```
if(s instanceof String) {
String t = (String)s;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry can you dumb this down a little bit for me a posted a new question with some extra code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a bit more information of types. If this helps you, remember to accept the answer by hitting the green check mark!